# Can't access my mail server on my computer, but on others I can

Tags: email, pop3

I'm sorry if this is the wrong forum to post this question on.

I have a mail server setup as pop, and I can access it on every computer I try, but on my personal computer I can't, it says that server is unreachable.

Other people in my network can access the same server, only I can't.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot of missing in the question, which makes it difficult to help troubleshoot. Please don't take my list of questions as discouraging, but could you add the information to your question?  Is there a network-path between your computer and the server (traceroute)? is the server pingable from your computer? Are there any firewalls/screening routers/proxies between you and the server? What is your OS? What is your mail-program? Can you try an `nmap` on the server (are you allowed to do that)?

Comment: Found the problem and solved it. Added the solution to the OP

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.